# Reading a file. How do i put the strings into character arrays?

Tags: c

I am reading a file and placing the info into arrays for later use. 
I have to open and then read and close.

I got the first 3 things done and it works good. But i am stumped on how to go forward with the next part. Also how would i know when i reach the end of the file. I know how long this one is because i made it. But if i was to run a unknown file i wouldn't know how many are in it.

My main problem right now is i have a string for the last file that i need to read. It will do that but it is returning the last one it pulls from the file. would a 2d array be good to use for the string and how would i do this.

```
int main(void)
{   
    FILE * pFile;
    char buf[40];
    int x[80];
    float y[80];
    int z[80];
    char str[40];


    pFile = fopen("testint.dat", "r");
    if (pFile != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            fgets(buf, 40, pFile);
            x[i] = atoi(buf);

            fgets(buf, 40, pFile);
            y[i] = atof(buf);

            fgets(buf, 40, pFile);
            z[i] = buf[0];

            fgets(str, 40, pFile);
            str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';

            printf("\n %s \n", str);

            printf("\n %i \n", x[i]);
            printf("\n %f \n", y[i]);
            printf("\n %c \n", z[i]);
        }

    }

    printf("\n\n %s \n", str);
    printf(" %i \n", x[0]);
    printf(" %f \n", y[1]);
    printf(" %c \n", z[2]);
    system("pause");

}
```

also here is the file info:

```
1 
1.1
a
aaaa
2 
2.2
b
bbbb
3 
3.3
c
cccc
4 
4.4
d
dddd
5 
5.5
e
eeee
```

Note: so far the code isn't returning errors. It is more the question of how i can proceed. (also anyone that can help me i owe you a beer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if i was to run a unknown file i wouldn't know how many are in it.

Replace

```
int i = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    fgets(buf, 40, pFile);
    x[i] = atoi(buf);

    fgets(buf, 40, pFile);
    y[i] = atof(buf);

    fgets(buf, 40, pFile);
    z[i] = buf[0];

    fgets(str, 40, pFile);
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("\n %s \n", str);

    printf("\n %i \n", x[i]);
    printf("\n %f \n", y[i]);
    printf("\n %c \n", z[i]);
}
```

with

```
int i = 0;
while (fgets(buf, 40, pFile))
{
    x[i] = atoi(buf);

    fgets(buf, 40, pFile);
    y[i] = atof(buf);

    fgets(buf, 40, pFile);
    z[i] = buf[0];

    fgets(str, 40, pFile);
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("\n %s \n", str);

    printf("\n %i \n", x[i]);
    printf("\n %f \n", y[i]);
    printf("\n %c \n", z[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Avoid the use of magic numbers like `40`, use `sizeof(buf)`

Answer (score 1):

Your question about when you reach the end of file, there is a function for it naming 'end of file' in short EOF heres a good example:

[Eof example](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Files/End.htm)